# Installing new icons/themes/etc

Tags: icons, root

I'm trying out 14.04 beta. When I used 13.10, I found a way to access the root folder, which I seem to have forgotten - I did that in order to add icon themes and cursor themes to Ubuntu, as there does not seem to be a user friendly way to do this---everything I read tells me to extract what I've downloaded to the icons folder, but there is no such folder I can get to without being told I do not have permission. When I had root access, I simply would open the root folder and extract the cursor/icon themes in the appropriate sub folders there. Is there a simple way to do what I want? I really don't think it should be this difficult.

Comment: Are you talking about /usr/share/themes, and /usr/share/icons?

Answer (score 1):

Just put the folders in `~/.icons` and `~/.themes`, which is the way to install them for your user specifically.